# FacesMessage listener

Tags: jsf, openfaces

What is the way for debugging JSF messages.
Can I implement some listener and catch all error messages that JSF is about to display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could with a [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) hook on the [`beforePhase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#beforePhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) of the [`PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html#RENDER_RESPONSE).

E.g.

```
public class MessagesListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        Iterator<FacesMessage> messageIterator = event.getFacesContext().getMessages();

        while (messageIterator.hasNext()) {
            FacesMessage message = messageIterator.next();
            // ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.MessagesListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Comment: Thank You BalusC. It helped a lot.