# JSF: remove client id (label, component id) from validation message without a custom message

Tags: validation, jsf, bean-validation

I have the following code:

```
<h:inputText id="it-date" value="#{myBean.myDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="it-date" />
```

When I enter the date `02/30/2012`, I get the following message:

```
j_idt5:it-date: '02/30/2012' could not be understood as a date. Example: 10/01/2012
```

Is it possible to remove `j_idt5:it-date:` including the colon *and* to keep the default message from Java?

I already tried to use the attribute `label`, but with that the colon remained. I don't want to use a custom message, because the default messages are already internationalized.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to get in between the message handling somehow to remove the colon because it is a fixed part of the message.

Checkout the message properties file, e.g. here: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/javax/faces/Messages.properties

The specific message/property in this case would be: 
    javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE={2}: ''{0}'' could not be understood as a date.

Check out the fixed colon after the `{2}` . If you want to get rid of it but keep the actual message you would need some way to get in between the message handling.

Mabye this answer from [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) is an option: 
[FacesMessage listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413908/facesmessage-listener)

Comment: @Abbadon: Thx for pointing out. Jarvana seems to down (currently). I exchanged the link to point to grepcode.com